# addEventListeners and best practices

Tags: actionscript-3, listeners

I'm using this simple code to retrieve a value from a PHP script:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    //
    public class URLTest extends MovieClip
    {
        //
        var scriptLoader:URLLoader;
        //
        public function URLTest()
        {
            scriptLoader = new URLLoader();
            scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
            scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);
        }
        //;
        public function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void
        {
            trace("Message sent.");
            trace($evt.target.data);
        }
        //
        public function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace("Message failed.");
        }
        //
        public function sendLoad(variable):void
        {
            var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mydomain/myapp/my.php");
            var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

            scriptVars.var1 = variable;

            scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

            scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
            trace(scriptLoader);
        }

    }

}
```

If you look at the URLTest constructor you'll find I initialize the listeners of an instance of URLLoader.

Is it a better practice to declare a method initListeners and call it everytime I call sendAndLoad? As a consequence, would it be a better practice that of removing the listeners inside the handleLoadError and handleLoadSuccesful methods? Are listeners cpu-intensive?

Btw, I don't understand why this question "appears to be subjective", since we're talking about performances, not programming style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your class is designed to be able to make multiple calls to the same webservice, I would definitely go for option 2. Consider this:

```
var loader:URLTest = new URLTest();
loader.sendLoad("a");
loader.sendLoad("b");
```

Now, if you re-use the same URLLoader for both calls, there is no way you can know which COMPLETE event is going to correspond to which call.

To solve this issue you would create a URLLoader (+ event listeners) for each call and put it in an Array to be able to identify it. When an answer comes from the server - be it a COMPLETE or an IOERROR - you can remove the event listeners and remove the identified URLLoader (the one that matches `event.currentTarget`) from the Array.

The performance issue is trivial here. There will be no performance hit for creating a bunch of event listeners as long as you remember to remove them when you're done with them. Otherwise the corresponding URLLoaders will not be garbage collected and will keep piling up in memory.

On a side note: there's absolutely no reason to extend from `MovieClip`. If you want your class to dispatch events, just extend `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: The call can be only one, I don't call sendLoad("a") and shorly after sendLoad("b"). I'm working on a website, not an application, and the listeners are ALWAYS used because I call the server many times (every time a link is clicked): I can't freeze them, I'm trying to under-use them. I extended MovieClip because this code was from a temporary Main of a Flash Professional project. Very interesting the tip about the event.currentTarget, thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying that you _would_ use it like that, I'm saying that you _could_. Which makes your class unclear - and more importantly, unsafe - in terms of how to use it. You should redesign it so that it can be used in only one way, i.e. the way _you_ intended it to be used.

Comment: Why unsafe? What you suggested can happen in no way.

Comment: I've a Controller: its UI representation is a Menu with 8 buttons. When you press the button every other button is disabled AND I call the sendLoad method. This is the context.

Comment: Through that specific UI it cannot happen. But if another developer comes along and wants to use your class (perhaps for another UI or a redesign of the current one), he may do it the wrong way and spend hours debugging. What you enforce through UI should already be enforced through the class itself, so you're absolutely 100% sure it can never happen. Now, I seem to understand that you're the only one working on this project, but it's still good practice to learn to think like that. You were specifically asking for best practices in your question...

Comment: Ok, in that sense I agree with you, absolutely.

Comment: One more question: it seems I can't access a currentTarget.name property. How do you apply the array technique you describe in your post?